# Is it possible to create triggers in cloudant database? -- similar to Relational Databases

Tags: triggers, document, cloudant, nosql

I want to insert the current timestamp in a document, whenever a new document is inserted into the Database. I know that this can be doe using triggers in relational Databases. But I am not sure how to do that in NosQL databases like Cloudant.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably worth you investigating update handlers:

> Update handlers are custom functions that live on Cloudant’s server that will create or update a document. This can, for example, provide server-side modification timestamps, and document updates to individual fields without the latest revision.

Source https://docs.cloudant.com/design_documents.html#update-handlers